# Ingress or Service with type: LoadBalancer

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, kubernetes-service

Kubernetes has both [Ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/) (in front of a Service) and Service with type: 
[LoadBalancer](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/create-external-load-balancer/).  These seem to do identical things: allow public traffic into the pods matching the service's selector.  What are the benefits and drawbacks of each?  In what scenarios would I choose one over the other?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ingress vs Load Balancer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45079988/ingress-vs-load-balancer)

Answer (score 4):

Ingress can be used to expose many services depending on the path or even multiple applications depending on the host or domain in the request.

A load balancer always exposes one service only.

Answer (score 3):

Assume that AWS, GCP or Azure is where your infrastructure located

[**Ingress:**](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/)

- Only work if you have ingress controller such as nginx-ingress-controller, traefik,...
- Many services could share the same ingress
- Name based virtual hosting
- path based routing
- Only one AWS ELB (or GCP load balancer for Google Cloud) is needed
- Recommend to follow this approach for most of use cases

[**serviceType LoadBalancer:**](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#publishing-services-service-types)

- each service would create separated AWS ELB (cost inefficiency, would be super expensive if you have more and more services later)
- Could be helpful in case you want to ensure maximum security / workload ( 1 ELB per service)

Comment: sums up properly. 
Importantly: One LoadBalancer per service will cost you much, whereas the Ingress will help you save the costs. Important consideration if there are many services.

Comment: Do you need on ELB (AWS/GCP) or can you just use an nginx ingress controller?