# Ingress resource vs NGINX ingress controller on Kubernetes

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I am setting up NGINX ingress controller on  AWS EKS.

I went through k8s Ingress resource and it is very helpful to understand we map LB ports to k8s service ports with e.g file def. I installed nginx controller till [pre-requisite step](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/#prerequisite-generic-deployment-command). Then the tutorial directs me to create an **ingress** resource.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/ingress-minikube/#create-an-ingress-resource

But below it is telling me to apply a **service** config. I am confused with this provider-specific step. Which is different in terms of `kind, version, spec` definition  (Service vs Ingress).

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/master/deploy/provider/aws/service-l7.yaml

I am missing something here?

Comment: What is your question here? What are you not understanding?

Comment: @cookiedough one is of type Service (nginx) and other is Ingress (k8s). I am confused what each is going to create on cluster

Comment: The ingress-controller is the public facing endpoint. It is essentially a loadbalancer service that has a public IP through which traffic is going to be directed to your different services. The ingress resources will be a step below the ingress controller, they will be assigned the same IP address as your ingress controller load balancing service. And based on the specs of your ingress, the controller routes the traffic to the corresponding service.

Comment: @cookiedough did I create the nginx controller on AWS with pre-requisite step? Next for is to create a ingress service. There I am confused which manifest kind, service to choose. k8s document says type: Ingress where as one on nginx says type: Service.

Comment: The `nginx-ingress` service of type loadbalancer is needed regardless of having an ingress or not. Create the load balancing service and then the ingress will come into play in case you have a service ready to take traffic.

Comment: I'll put some code in an answer, can't fit everything here.

Comment: @cookiedough Great. So `nginx-ingress` is actual load balancer that will be provisioned on public subnet and managed by controller created in pre-req step. Once this is ready I can create k8s Ingress Service objects to route the traffic. Is my understanding inline  with what you explained?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189231/discussion-between-pat-and-cookiedough).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a concept that is at first a little tricky to wrap your head around. The Nginx ingress controller is nothing but a service of type `LoadBalancer`. What is does is be the public-facing endpoint for your services. The IP address assigned to this service can route traffic to multiple services. So you can go ahead and define your services as `ClusterIP` and have them exposed through the Nginx ingress controller.

Here's a diagram to portray the concept a little better:
[image: nginx-ingress]
[image source](https://www.nginx.com/blog/announcing-nginx-ingress-controller-for-kubernetes-release-1-3-0/)

On that note, if you have acquired a static IP for your service, you need to assign it to your Nginx ingress-controller. So what is an ingress? Ingress is basically a way for you to communicate to your Nginx ingress-controller how to direct traffic incoming to your LB public IP. So as it is clear now, you have one loadbalancer service, and multiple ingress resources. Each ingress corresponds to a single service that can change based on how you define your services, but you get the idea.

Let's get into some yaml code. As mentioned, you will need the ingress controller service regardless of how many ingress resources you have. So go ahead and apply [this code](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/master/deploy/provider/aws/service-l7.yaml) on your EKS cluster.

Now let's see how you would expose your pod to the world through Nginx-ingress. Say you have a `wordpress` deployment. You can define a simple `ClusterIP` service for this app:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: ${WORDPRESS_APP}
  namespace: ${NAMESPACE}
  name: ${WORDPRESS_APP}
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
  - port: 9000
    targetPort: 9000
    name: ${WORDPRESS_APP}
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 80
    protocol: TCP
    name: http
  - port: 443
    targetPort: 443
    protocol: TCP
    name: https
  selector:
    app: ${WORDPRESS_APP}
```

This creates a service for your `wordpress` app which is not accessible outside of the cluster. Now you can create an ingress resource to expose this service:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  namespace: ${NAMESPACE}
  name: ${INGRESS_NAME}
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    kubernetes.io/tls-acme: "true"
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - ${URL}
    secretName: ${TLS_SECRET}
  rules:
  - host: ${URL}
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: ${WORDPRESS_APP}
          servicePort: 80
```

Now if you run `kubectl get svc` you can see the following:

```
NAME                      TYPE          CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP    PORT(S)                   AGE
wordpress                 ClusterIP     10.23.XXX.XX   <none>         9000/TCP,80/TCP,443/TCP   1m
nginx-ingress-controller  LoadBalancer  10.23.XXX.XX    XX.XX.XXX.XXX  80:X/TCP,443:X/TCP   1m
```

Now you can access your `wordpress` service through the URL defined, which maps to the public IP of your ingress controller LB service.

Comment: Also take a look at the correct answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50966300/whats-the-difference-between-exposing-nginx-as-load-balancer-vs-ingress-control).

Comment: ingress is not a service. kubectl get services: ingress not included.

Answer (score 3):

the NGINX ingress controller is the actual process that shapes your traffic to your services. basically like the nginx or loadbalancer installation on a traditional vm. 
the ingress resource (kind: Ingress) is more like the nginx-config on your old VM, where you would define host mappings, paths and proxies.