# Possible to have both an l4 and l7 ingress-nginx?

Tags: kubernetes, nginx-ingress

Is it possible to have ingress-nginx serve both l4 and l7 in with one ELB? I'm assuming that it's not based on the following annotation:

```
service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-proxy-protocol: "*"
```

I'm hoping somebody tells me that I'm wrong ;)

Answer (score 1):

L4 load balancer is actually  forwarding traffic to the [Nodeport](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#nodeport).
I would say that this is not possible just because [ingress-nginx](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx) acts as balancer, that only forwards HTTP and HTTPS traffic.

However you can look into [NGINX Plus](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/load-balancer/tcp-udp-load-balancer/) [side](https://www.nginx.com/products/nginx/):

> In NGINX Plus Release 5 and later, NGINX Plus can proxy and load
> balance Transmission Control Protocol) (TCP) traffic. TCP is the
> protocol for many popular applications and services, such as LDAP,
> MySQL, and RTMP.
>
> In NGINX Plus Release 9 and later, NGINX Plus can proxy and load
> balance UDP traffic. UDP (User Datagram Protocol) is the protocol for
> many popular nontransactional applications, such as DNS, syslog, and
> RADIUS

Also, check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50967732/9929015) to be familiar on how it works.