# Route incoming traffic in Docker swarm setup

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-compose, docker-swarm

I'll have a similar setup to this (one node only):

```
          internet
             |
      [ nginx proxy]
             |
          [ node ]
  --|-----|--  --|-----|--
   [ Service A]-[ Service B]
```

I want to achieve some kind of routing, e.g. like this:

> - `https://server.com/nginx` routes the traffic to the nginx, which forwards it to the cluster
> - `https://server.com/nginx/a` routes the traffic to `Service A`
> - `https://server.com/nginx/b` routes the traffic to `Service B`

**Is there a solution from `docker` (cluster internal) which can route traffic depending on the `/path/`?**

I was using `kubernetes` before, where I had the option do define a `path` within an `ingress`. Is there something similar in `docker`?

Answer (score 0):

I have not used ingress, but I believe it just wraps NGINX. As far as I know, docker has no equivalent, but you can, of course, make your own NGINX service that will perform this task for you. A quick example might look like:

```
server {
    listen      80;
    server_name example.org www.example.org;
    root        /data/www;

    location / {
        index   index.html index.php;
    }

    location ~* \.(gif|jpg|png)$ {
        expires 30d;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass  php_container_name:9000; //NOTE THE CONTAINER *NAME* NOT IP
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME
                      $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include       fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

(taken from http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html)

You would then launch a container built with nginx and your config. Note that you would refer to your other services by name.

Edit: this post - [Kubernetes: Ingress vs Load Balancer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45079988/kubernetes-ingress-vs-load-balancer?rq=1) may explain more and possibly help you translate your current kubernetes solution.