# Kubernetes cloud provider

Tags: kubernetes

I'm new to Kubernetes and their is a concept I'm not sure to fully understand: Cloud Providers.

- I have installed my Kubernetes cluster using RKE (Rancher engine).
- My cluster is set on top of rancher2.
- My nodes are Virtual Machines hosted an OVH server.

I manage to have running applications with L7 ingresses and ClusterIP services but everytime I try to have a L4 LoadBalancer, the LoadBalancer is stuck in pending state. According to https://github.com/rancher/rancher/issues/14424 this is because I doesn't have any CloudProvider.

But what is exactly the purpose of a CloudProvider? Isn't it to run Kubernetes nodes, pods, ... on the cloud? If yes, why should I bother getting a CloudProvider if my applications are pods are already on the cloud and accessible from the outside thanks to my configuration.

So my following questions are:

- What is exactly the role of a CloudProvider?
- Is it useful in my environment ?
- Is it mandatory to have a CloudProvider in order to run L4 Load Balancer ?
- What is the alternative to a L4 LoadBalancer ?
- Can't I have custom CloudProvider not relying on one of those listed here: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/cloud-providers/ ? Like a self-hosted CloudProvider running NGINX or something ?

Thanks for any clarification/recommandation on this subject. -

Answer (score 0):

In case of [Rancher](https://github.com/rancher/rancher-cloud-controller-manager)

> An external **cloud provider** is a kubernetes controller that runs
>   cloud provider-specific loops required for the functioning of
>   kubernetes. These loops were originally a part of the
>   kube-controller-manager, but they were tightly coupling the
>   kube-controller-manager to cloud-provider specific code. In order to
>   free the kubernetes project of this dependency, the
>   cloud-controller-manager was introduced.

This brings us to the topic of [Kubernetes Cloud Controller Manager](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/running-cloud-controller/)

> Kubernetes v1.6 introduced a new binary called
>   cloud-controller-manager. cloud-controller-manager is a daemon that
>   embeds cloud-specific control loops. These cloud-specific control
>   loops were originally in the kube-controller-manager. Since cloud
>   providers develop and release at a different pace compared to the
>   Kubernetes project, abstracting the provider-specific code to the
>   cloud-controller-manager binary allows cloud vendors to evolve
>   independently from the core Kubernetes code.

Regarding the LoadBalancer part:

- There is a [guide](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/create-external-load-balancer/) showing how to create an External Load Balancer. It says:

> You need to have a Kubernetes cluster, and the kubectl command-line
>   tool must be configured to communicate with your cluster.

- If you need an alternative however, you may want to use [Ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/)

> An API object that manages external access to the services in a
>   cluster, typically HTTP. Ingress can provide load balancing, SSL
>   termination and name-based virtual hosting.

If you want to get a better idea of this concept than check out [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45079988/ingress-vs-load-balancer).

And lastly regarding the custom [Cloud Provider](https://rancher.com/docs/rke/latest/en/config-options/cloud-providers/custom/). It is possible to enable a different cloud provider for RKE:

> If you want to enable a different cloud provider, RKE allows for
>   custom cloud provider options. A name must be provided and the custom
>   Cloud Provider options can be passed in as a multiline string in
>   `customCloudProvider`.

I hope it helps.